# Laravel not reading database.php config correctly

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, php-7

I'm having a weird issue with Laravel where it is looking for the connection `mysql` when there is no connection called `mysql`. In my `database.php` config, I have the default connection set to:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'permissions'),
```

and in my `.env` file, I have the line:

```
DB_CONNECTION=permissions
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
local.ERROR: InvalidArgumentException: Database [mysql] not configured. in D:\Development\Permissions\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager.php:239
Stack trace:
#0 D:\Development\Permissions\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager.php(158): Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager->getConfig('mysql')
#1 D:\Development\Permissions\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager.php(68): Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager->makeConnection('mysql')
#2 D:\Development\Permissions\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(3348): Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager->connection('mysql')
#3 D:\Development\Permissions\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(3314): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::resolveConnection(NULL)
```

I traced the issue to a call to `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager->getDefaultConnection()`. For some reason even though the default connection is set to `permissions`, the connection name that returns is `mysql`. Here is the function for reference:

```
public function getDefaultConnection()
{
    return $this->app['config']['database.default'];
}
```

This issue is apearing on a Windows 10 box running ampps, but not an issue when running through homestead.

EDIT:

I can confirm that it is the `'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'permissions'),` line in the `database.php` file because when it is changed to be `'default' => 'permissions'`, the application works as expected.

Comment: Tried to empty your config cache? (`php artisan config:clear`)

Comment: I ran that command twice.

Comment: Alright. Have you setup your "permissions" connection? If yes, please show us the code.

Comment: Please see my edit. It is not an issue with the individual connections, but an issue with the `DatabaseManager` class retrieving the incorrect default connection name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please run the following commands.

To clear cache -

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Clear config cache

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Then ***restart your laravel server***. It should be working by now.